# drupal - Change the view in the module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I want to change the view of the module depending on the Url. All in php. 
I created two views putting this data:

```
function config_services_block_info() {   
 $blocks['config_services'] = array(
   // The name that will appear in the block list.
   'info' => t('Services'),
   // Default setting.
   'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,   );   
 $blocks['orderservices'] = array(
   // The name that will appear in the block list.
   'info' => t('Order Services'),
   // Default setting.
   'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,   );
 return $blocks; 
}

function config_services_block_view($delta = '') {   switch ($delta) {
  case 'config_services':
    ...
    block[content] = ...;
    return block;
  break;
  case 'orderservices':
    ...
    block[content] = ...;
    return block;
  break;   } }

function config_services_menu() {   $items = array();  
  $items['config_services/orderservices'] = array(
  'title' => t('Order Services'),
  'page callback' => array('_config_services_orderservices_page'),
  'access arguments' => array('order config_services content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, //Will appear in block.   );   return $items; }
```

In _config_services_orderservices_page() I think this but no work:

```
function _config_services_orderservices_page() {
  config_services_block_view('orderservices');
}
```

The first view works, the problem is when I want the second view. How I change the view for the url: http:(slash)(slash)*name-web*/config_services/orderservices

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the condition you want to change the view, the condition could be checked inside `_config_services_orderservices_page()` function, and specific block could be displayed.

```
function _config_services_orderservices_page() {
  if (your_condition == 'orderservices') {
    config_services_block_view('orderservices');
  }
  if (other_condition == 'config_services') {
    config_services_block_view('config_services');
  }
}
```

On a side note, *view* in Drupal means something totally different. It is the most popular and most used module overall. Please visit the [project page](https://drupal.org/project/views), and the [documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views).
And what you refer to is about [blocks](https://drupal.org/documentation/blocks).

Comment: Maybe you are right. I'm new in Drupal. I thought I wanted was a view for the function's name block_view.